# WebApi 2 AssemblyResolver

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have created a controller assembly containing all my controllers in WebApi 2.0 and followed this article - https://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/ and created a CustomAssemblyResolver and added code to replace the assembly resolver in Application_Start. Here's what my code looks like:

My CustomAssemblyResolver:

```
public class CustomAssemblyResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
    public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        ICollection<Assembly> baseAssemblies = base.GetAssemblies();
        List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>(baseAssemblies);

        string thirdPartySource = "C:\\Research\\ExCoWebApi\\ExternalControllers";

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(thirdPartySource))
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(thirdPartySource))
            {
                foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(thirdPartySource, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    if (Path.GetExtension(file) == ".dll")
                    {
                        var externalAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);

                        baseAssemblies.Add(externalAssembly);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return baseAssemblies;
    }
}
```

My Application_Start:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Debugger.Launch();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new CustomAssemblyResolver());            


    }
```

As you can see I'm replacing the default assembly resolver with a CustomAssemblyResolver.

Here's how I'm registering route to the third party controller:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {            
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Test",
            routeTemplate: "api/thirdparty/math",
            defaults: new { controller = "Math" }
        );            
    }
```

This is how my MathController looks like that lives in a separate assembly:

```
public class MathController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public int AddValues(MathRequest request)
    {
        int response = MathOperations.Add(request.Value1, request.Value2);
        return response;
    }
}
```

This is the endpoint I hit via postman: http://localhost/ExCoWebApi/api/thirdparty/math with a POST operation and MathRequest JSON string in the Body and this is what I get as a response:

{
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/ExCoWebApi/api/thirdparty/math'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'Math'."
}

After debugging I found that the AssemblyResolver does get replaced with CustomAssemblyResolver at the Application Start but the problem is the GetAssemblies() method of CustomAssemblyResolver doesn't get called. Hence the assembly containing MathController doesn't get loaded.

What am I missing here??

**EDIT**

In a desperate effort to finding solution to this I stood up a test method in which I build my own HttpConfiguration object and replace the AssemblyResolver in it and it works like a charm! The GetAssemblies() function from the CustomAssemblyResolver gets called and I'm able to call my external controller.. I wonder if there's a difference in the HttpConfiguration object that is returned from "GlobalConfiguration.Configuration" vs. instantiating one manually.. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code for my test method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestExternalControllerCall()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = GetClient();
            MathRequest mathReq = new MathRequest { Value1 = 10, Value2 = 20 };
            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(string.Concat("http://localhost/api/thirdparty/math"), mathReq).Result;
            var entResponse = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<int>().Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    private HttpClient GetClient()
    {            
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Test",
            routeTemplate: "api/thirdparty/math",
            defaults: new { controller = "Math" }
        );
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new CustomAssemblyResolver());
        HttpServer server = new HttpServer(config);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(server);
        return client;        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue:

The reason why the GetAssemblies() was not getting called is because the callback method (WebApiConfig.Register) set for GlobalConfiguration.Configure which was calling "config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();". The

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new CustomAssemblyResolver());`

code actually belongs in the callback method configured in GlobalConfiguration.Configure as opposed to Global.asax if you have a callback set for GlobalConfiguration.Configure. So I moved the IAssemblyResolver replace statement to the Register method in WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new CustomAssemblyResolver());

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();            
    }
}
```